# UseSerilog unknown reference in ConfigureWebHostDefaults

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

i followed few tutorials and im stuck building the default dotnet 3.1 with serilog
in program.cs
this line wont build
here is the code
https://github.com/guymalka/serilog-dotnetcore/blob/master/Program.cs
what reference do I need to add here?

Comment: [this tutorial](https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/) (reference the tutorials in your question please), mentions `Seriog.AspNetCore` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First include nuget package reference in your .csproj file:

```cs
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.4.0" />
```

and `dotnet restore` your project.
After that import the Serilog namespace in your `Program.cs` file (you could do that in `Startup` as well):

```cs
using Serilog;
```

That should be enough for you to register Serilog like so:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog()
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
      webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

Note that if you wish to configure other aspects, e.g., your sinks, with Serilog chances are you'll have to include separate packages:

```cs
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
```